# Retrieving photos taken without a memory card

Tags: dslr

We went out for a picnic and took lots of photos but we didn't spot that there was no memory card in the camera until afterwards.

If there was no memory card in Digital SLR camera is there a way to get back the photos taken?

Some images are shown when the camera is connected to a laptop but they are not saved and not detected.

Comment: There is a setting which prevents you from taking pcitures without a memory card. You definitely should enable this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately most (if not all) DSLRs have no onboard memory so your out of luck the shutter clicked but no photo was actually taken or saved anywhere

Comment: Most DSLRs do have an internal buffer which allows demo shots taken when there is no card in the camera to be displayed on the rear LCD. But having said that, getting those images off camera is a difficult, if not impossible, proposition.